# Magento 2 show/hide add to cart button based on section data

Tags: magento2, addtocart, caching, section, enable-disable

I need to show/hide the add-to-cart button based on some custom values. These values are stored in a product attribute. The values are updated at the time of order creation.

I am using sections.xml for this to overcome the cache issue. But I am facing issues while getting the product id in the source map php file.

I am referred the below link to do this.
https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-use-private-content-or-sections-in-magento-2/

Comment: Bro can you take a look at my question, its not related to your question, i just thought you may know the answer. here is my question
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358034/magento2-4-how-to-sort-product-by-best-selling-and-best-reviewed-produc

Comment: @PyarayAfzel please don't spam in comment.

Comment: @Jancy Abraham Please provide more details because it's not clear how a private content is related to some specific attributes in your product and what is logic to show/hide add to cart button. Do you want to use section logic to load private content and pass current product id for resolve something?

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk I have created a deal functionality. In that only limited qtys are available. After each order the deal qty is reduced. I want to hide the addtocart button when the deal qty exceeds. I am saving this deal in a separate table with product id, deal qty and deal sale qty.

Comment: @JancyAbraham If you want to store all those data in client local storage you can use section functionality, but i don't recommend to do in this way (This is overhead with server load and browser as well). Better to create custom controller action to receive actual qty for product and create JS component with AJAX query for receive this data from server for product and render content based on this value. P.S. Magento flush affected product pages cache after each purchase.

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk Yes, I will do it with ajax. The actual issue is with the cache.

Comment: Issue with cache on client side or on server side? Did you try to do `customerData.reload('custom_section', true)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this with sections.

I am passing the values as json in the CustomSection.php file in app/code/Namespace/Module/CustomerData.

```
  <?php
    namespace Namespace\Module\CustomerData;
    use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;
    
    class CustomSection implements SectionSourceInterface
    {
        public function getSectionData()
        {
            return [
                'customdata' => "We are getting data from custom section",
                'deal'=> json_encode([['id'=>'14','display'=>'true'],['id'=>'11','display'=>'false']]),
            ];
        }
    }
```

Here is the phtml file

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct();
$buttonTitle ="Add To Cart"; ?>

<div class="aureatelabs-custom-section"data-bind="scope: 'section'">
    <p data-bind="text: customsection().customdata"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: customsection().deal"></p>
    <!--ko foreach: JSON.parse(customsection().deal)-->    
        <!--ko if: ($data.id == <?php echo $_product->getId()?> && $data.display == true)-->
        
            <p class="label" data-bind="text: id"></p>
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
            </button>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "section": {
                        "component": "Namespace_Module/js/section"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```